# Word for a reservoir of *something* at my disposal

Tags: single-word-requests, phrases, expressions

I am looking for a word or phrase that describes the following:

A customer purchases software and receives 10 hours of training that he can use according to his wants and needs.

The native language expression translates into "Hour Bank", but I don't know if that is proper, or if there is another accepted expression.

> You have 10 hours in your ____________.

Comment: *Account*, perhaps?

Comment: @Mick - please turn this into an answer as it's the most suitable term for this. Kitty is too informal for business use and I've only ever heard it applied to a pool of money.

Comment: @Mick I agree with Jon Larby.

Answer (score 2):

As suggested by Mick, how about *account*?

M-W:

> [*account*](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/account): a
>   formal business arrangement providing for regular dealings or services
>   (as banking, advertising, or store credit) and involving the
>   establishment and maintenance of an account

Your example:

> You have 10 hours in your training account.

*Credit* is another relevant word, to be used with account.

From M-W:

> [*credit*](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/credit): the
>   balance in a person's favor in an account

Example:

> We have added a 10-hour training 
>   *credit* to your account.
>
> We have *credited* your account with 10 hours of training that you can
>   use as you see fit.

Answer (score 0):

I think this word, although not directly contextual, can be used in your context too:

> **Kitty** ([Source](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/kitty))

You have 10 hours in your **kitty**.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps it is an ***allowance***.

> You have 10 hours in your ***allowance***.

M-W:

> **[allowance](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/allowance)**
>   *noun*
>
> **1 c** :  a fixed or available amount : *provide an **allowance** of time for recreation*
>
> a monthly allowance for household expenses
>   Each of their children
>   gets a weekly allowance of five dollars.